# difference between ~ and >= in node package

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, package, version

2 questions

- What is the difference between both
- how can i change a globally installed grunt-node inspector to use >=

  ```
  "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.2.0"

  "grunt-node-inspector": ">=0.2.0"
  ```

`npm -v grunt-node-inspector`    comes out to be   3.6.0

how can i change it to >=0.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 2):

'~' or tilde means Approximately equivalent to version. Matches the most recent minor version (the middle number). ~0.2.0 will be equivalent to all 0.2.* versions but not 0.3.0.
And '>=version' means greater than or equal to

Refer  https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Can you tell how can i change the version of globally installed package ?
This is the problem i am facing https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-debug/issues/7 and the solution from "russfrisch" is what i need to try.

Comment: To find out which packages need to be updated, you can use (Without quotes) 
 >> 'npm outdated -g --depth=0'
to update global packages use (Without quotes) 
>> 'npm update -g'